# why is my global table being considered nil?

Tags: printing, lua, runtime-error, null, lua-table

**background:**

I am trying to teach myself Lua and I am having difficulty understanding why a table is being considered nil when it has data inside it. Can anyone break it down for me why I am getting this error message from the code snippet below? It is one of my first programs and i really need to get these few concepts down before moving on to my real project. Thanks!

**error message:**

```
C:\Users\<user>\Desktop>lua luaCrap.lua
lua: luaCrap.lua:7: attempt to call global 'entry' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        luaCrap.lua:7: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

**code:**

```
--this creates the function to print
function fwrite (fmt, ...)
  return io.write(string.format(fmt, unpack(arg)))
end

--this is my table of strings to print
entry{
    title = "test",
    org = "org",
    url = "http://www.google.com/",
    contact = "someone",
    description = [[
                    test1
                    test2
                    test3]]
}

--this is to print the tables first value  
fwrite(entry[1])

--failed loop attempt to print table
-- for i = 1, #entry, 1 do
    -- local entryPrint = entry[i] or 'Fail'
    -- fwrite(entryPrint)
-- end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are missing the assignment to entry.

you need to change the entry code to this:

```
entry = 
{
    title = "test",
    org = "org",
    url = "http://www.google.com/",
    contact = "someone",
    description = [[
                    test1
                    test2
                    test3]]
}
```

to clarify the error message, parens are assumed in certain contexts, like when you have a table directly following a label. the interpreter thinks you're trying to pass a table to a function called `entry`, which it can't find. it assumes you really meant this:

```
entry({title = "test", ...})
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing that. I dont really see anything different between your code and mine. just that the bracket { is on a new line. Is that it?

Comment: no, you are missing the assignment operator `=`. my example includes it.

Comment: thank you! right after you wrote that, i looked at my entry and had that epiphany moment haha. stackoverflow says i have to wait 5 more minutes before accepting your answer.